# java socket and nginx

Tags: java, sockets, nginx, serversocket

I am trying to work with socket connections via nginx

1. I start server socket on some port (for example 9111), accept
   sockets connection and try to read 2 POST requests.
2. Next, I start socket client, which connects to server socket and sends 2 POST requests.

   - When I start client socket on 9111  - everything works as expected.
   - When I start client socket on 80 (which should we forwarded by nginx 
     to 9111 port)  - only one first message read.

Note please that 
 - it is simplified examples and content body is empty to shrink it
 - Also I have tried a lot of nginx configuration combinations, with empty Connection header or 'keep-alive' etc etc

What am I doing wrong?

---

Server side

```
val serverSock = new ServerSocket(9111)
println(s"Server socket started")

while (true) {
    val sock = serverSock.accept()
    val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream, "UTF8"))

    println(s"Socket accepted: $sock")
    println()

    def readRequest() = {
        println("Reading...")

        var line = reader.readLine()

        // Between headers and content should be empty line. Content is empty.
        while (line != null && line.nonEmpty) {
            println(s"Line: $line")

            line = reader.readLine()
        }

        println("Request read.")
        println()
    }

    readRequest()
    readRequest()

    sock.close()
}
```

Client side

```
// val sock = new Socket("localhost", 80)  // Works incorrect. Only one message read on server side.
val sock = new Socket("localhost", 9111) // Works fine. Both messages read on server side.

val writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream, "UTF8"))

def postEmptyRequest(): Unit = {
    writer.write("POST /socket HTTP/1.1\r\n")
    writer.write(s"Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n")
    writer.write(s"Content-Length: 0\r\n")
    writer.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n")
    writer.write("\r\n")

    writer.flush()
}

postEmptyRequest()
postEmptyRequest()

Thread.sleep(100)

sock.close()
```

nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Connection "";

           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9111;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
```

Server side logs without nginx (port 9111)

```
Server socket started
Socket accepted: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=60915,localport=9111]

Reading...
Line: POST /socket HTTP/1.1
Line: Host: 127.0.0.1
Line: Content-Length: 0
Line: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Request read.

Reading...
Line: POST /socket HTTP/1.1
Line: Host: 127.0.0.1
Line: Content-Length: 0
Line: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Request read.
```

Server side logs with nginx (port 80)

```
Socket accepted: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=61089,localport=9111]

Reading...
Line: POST /socket HTTP/1.1
Line: X-Real-IP: 127.0.0.1
Line: X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
Line: Host: 127.0.0.1
Line: X-NginX-Proxy: true
Line: Content-Length: 0
Line: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Request read.

Reading...
Request read.
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I have to send responses from server 
..
writer.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n")
etc

Comment: Can you tell me what you did exactly, i'm having the same problem